# How do i Get Object tags using python boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to get tags of objects from s3 bucket.

i have tried bucket = s3.BucketTagging(BUCKET_TWO).
But i want get tags of individual objects in the bucket

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Official Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_tagging) you can use `get_object_tagging` to retrieve all the custom tags at an object level.

Example:

```
response = client.get_object_tagging(
    Bucket='string',
    Key='string',
    VersionId='string',
    ExpectedBucketOwner='string',
    RequestPayer='requester'
)
```